# REST Routes depending on Roles

Tags: design-patterns, rest

I'm currently working on a project which will use a REST API and that's exactly what I'm working on and I'm using nodejs with express, mongodb and mongoose.

I've users that can have 4 different roles: user, secretary, worker and manager. Let's say they can all access the kits document but they can do different actions towards it depending on the item's current state. The user asks for a repair and is only able to view his own requests, the worker can only view/act if it got approved by the manager and the manager can approve/view all the existing repair requests.

I was currently using the following endpoints:

```
get /api/repairs - all the items, can be viewed by the manager
get /api/repairs/me - all the items created by the user that is accessing it
get /api/repairs/me/:id - detail of an item created by the user that is accessing it
```

What routes should I create for the other roles? This is my first time working with this and even though I searched for the best practices, I can't really tell what is the best in this case. Thanks in advance.

I've thought about these but I'm not exactly sure if that's the best practice.

```
'/api/users/repairs/' GET
'/api/users/repairs/:id' GET
'/api/workers/repairs/' GET
'/api/workers/repairs/:id' GET
'/api/workers/repairs/:id/complete' PATCH - to complete a repair request 
'/api/workers/repairs/:id/reschedule' PATCH - to reschedule a request
'/api/managers/repairs/' GET
'/api/managers/repairs/:id' GET
'/api/managers/repairs/:id/' PATCH - to edit the request
```

Comment: use a JWT or some other kind of other session token to identify the user and his rights and hide everything as an implementation detail only exposing the `/api/repairs` while managing things based on the context.

Answer (score 1):

If the following operations

- `/api/users/repairs`
- `/api/workers/repairs`
- `/api/managers/repairs`

each return `Repair[]`, then I would simply use `/api/repairs` and return the repairs accessible to the user making the request.

I would only create separate routes and operations if the shape of the response is different, e.g.

- `/api/users/repairs` returns `UserRepair[]`
- `/api/workers/repairs` returns `WorkerRepair[]`
- `/api/managers/repairs` returns `ManagerRepair[]`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the only route you should be using is:

**GET**: /api/repairs

**PATCH**: /api/repairs

Yes, only **one**. Say you want to extract details from it ? You use GET method,

**GET**: /api/repairs [Will return whatever is public]

**GET**: /api/repairs/{sessionKey/secretKey} [Return what belongs to user]

**GET**: /api/repairs/{sessionKey/secretKey}&{id} [Return item by id belongs to user]*

Same goes for patch(if you need to update something), just the REST method will be different, your backend should automatically be able to distinguish the difference in terms of REST method and query provided.

***Note: Do not query information in PATCH instead provide it in body***

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resources.

In a hypermedia api (which is what REST [really means](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)), the clients don't care either; they would simply be following whatever links were provided by the server.

> Let's say they can all access the kits document but they can do different actions towards it depending on the item's current state

I'd encourage you to review Jim Webber's talk [REST in the Large](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc).

> HTTP is the application protocol for a 1950s office, where all work is transacted by politely placing documents in in-trays; and then some side effect of placing that document in an in-tray causes some business activity to occur.

Your business process is basically a big manila folder with a bunch of forms in it.  Here's the repair request, here's the manager's approval, here's the invoice, here's the work order, and so on.

```
/api/repairs/:id/request
/api/repairs/:id/approval
/api/repairs/:id/work-order
/api/repairs/:id/invoice
/api/repairs/:id/schedule
...
```

So for instance, only the manager is allowed to PUT/PATCH the approval resource, and until that is done the work-order resource returns `403` or `404` if the worker tries to access the work order before it has been approved, the customer can only see those resources she is authorized to see, and everybody gets a big `403` if they color outside the lines.